# Flutter Targeting a Specific Android Version

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, version

Is there an easy way to make your sure app can run on a specific version or higher. For example Android 8 or higher. I understand I can change the compilesdkversion to test it on different version. It ends up giving me errors because of firebase being too up to date so I roll it back. I feel like I am just guessing and running. I tried looking at the changelog and versioning but there is not too much documentation where the cutoffs are. Firebase is just one package I have done it for all my packages. I feel like there has to be an easier way to support older versions of android. I dont want just people with android 12/13 to be able to install my app.

Answer (score 2):

To change a minimum target version and highest target version, you need to change a simple setting in `android/app/build.gradle` file. The required variables to be changed are `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion`.

```
    defaultConfig {
        // code skipped
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 30
    }
```

You can read more the android SDK version [here](https://source.android.com/setup/start/build-numbers)